# How to find area of rectangle in interval?

Tags: area, multiple-integral

Calculate area of rectangle

$I=\left[0,3\right] \times \left[0,8\right] $

$A=\int_{I}^{} \! 1d(x,y) \, $

Can someone give me hint, how to calculate area with the informations they gave me. I think I should use multiple integrals, but I am not sure how excatly I neet to determine borders with the help of given interval.

Comment: What is the range for $x$ given $I$? What is the range for $y$? Can you use that information to construct a double integral?

Answer (score 0):

The region is a rectangle, so this is a simple iterated integral. The $x$ coordinate goes from $0$ to $3$, and the $y$ coordinate goes from $0$ to $8$. So you can either integrate $dx$ from $0$ to $3$ first, or $dy $ from $0$ to $8$ first, then integrate that result with respect to the other coordinate. This can simply be thought of as the area of a rectangle with length $8$ and width $3$.

Comment: $A=\int_{0}^{8} \! \int_{0}^{3} \! \, dx \, dy $ Do you mean just simply like this?

Comment: That's it! Note that you could reverse the order of integration in this case, so you could do $A=\int_{0}^{8} \! \int_{0}^{3} \! \, dx \, dy$ or $A=\int_{0}^{3} \! \int_{0}^{8} \! \, dy \, dx$